# Remove Mass Assignment Vulnerability

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, mass-assignment

I have a model `A` which consists of this line :

```
attr_accessible :name, :address, :street_id
```

It shows me that there exists a dangerous attribute (`:street_id`) for mass assignment. I have used the model `A` at a place as :

```
A.new(:name => "Test", :address => "RandomPlace", :street_id => 1)
```

What should I change so that this issue gets resolved?

`Edit` :

I tried changing the code as :

```
attr_accessible :name, :address
attr_protected :street_id

a = A.new(:name => "Test", :address => "RandomPlace")
a.street_id = 1
```

Will this work?

Comment: You can make **Street** as an association of model **A** and build it while creating a record for model **A**

Comment: What warns you about the dangerous attribute?

Comment: a tool which analyses code.

Comment: Keep in mind a lot of those tools throw false positives. idk in this case as I haven't fully delved into it but it's something to keep in mind.

Comment: Yes, I will but is my edit correct?